# I am using wordpress in my development but i duplicated the home page the error starts to appear

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

Deprecated: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in /home/tnohmksg/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 7127

How to solve this error on a wordpress website?

I deleted the pages duplicated today, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is a PHP function that can be used to determine the position of a possible subset (the needle) in a supposed superset (the haystack). This is its description:

```
 strpos(string $haystack, string $needle, int $offset = 0): int|false
```

- `$haystack`: a `string` that will be searched in order to find the `$needle`
- `$needle`: a `string` that will be searched for in the `$haystack`
- `$offset`: the number of characters at the start of `$haystack` (or its end, if `$offset` happens to be negative) to jump over and ignore

Now, the problem in your question clearly suggests that your code calls `strpos` at some place and passes `null` rather than a string and this is deprecated.

The solution is to look into the place where it happens and either:

- default your haystack to something, like `$haystack ?? ''`
- check for `$haystack` to have a proper value
- change some setting that may be assumed to have a value
- fix the logic that uses the function in question
- upgrade Wordpress

**But don't forget that we need to be very careful when considering the application of fixes in Wordpress's codebase, because they tend to make Wordpress updates increasingly more difficult, so whatever your solution of choice will be, you should try to make sure that you apply your fix in your code/settings rather than Wordpress's codebase.**

Now, if we check the current version of this Wordpress file at the time of this writing, then we can find this:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ceb151029c0f31361cd924f5a19b4ec135d77db3/wp-includes/functions.php#L7127

[image]

Which means that you might be on an older version or a different branch. You will need to check what commit hash are you on, running `git log` will show you what the latest commits were along their hash and you can check both the code as it is in your end (perhaps there are some unversioned changes) as well as the official status of this file as per the commit hash you are on.